# F# - MS Access upload tab delimited text data

Tags: database, ms-access, f#

I am trying to upload a tab delimited text file to an Access database. I have the following code:

```
Let connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\...\testdb.accdb;Security Info=False;"
let connection = new OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
connection.Open()
let query = "SELECT * INTO [temp] FROM [Text;DATABASE=C\...].[name.txt]"
let command = new OleDb.OleDbCommand(query,connection)
command.Connection.Open()
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This code works fine but how do I separate the data in MS Access so that its not all put into one column?

Also, is there a way to get the **data or table import** query string generated from within MS Access so I can take it and use it in F#.

Comment: You will need a schema.ini file unless you wish to work with DAO ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: I tried this and there seems to be some issues with microsoft text drivers, ie i cant find it even after downloading and installing the latest. I have seen similar issues in another discussion with no solution. Is there a way to adjust the query somehow to account for the fact that the data is tab delimited?

Comment: Are you really referring to Source=C:\...\? Have you tried the full path?

Comment: The above code is fine. I just write C:\...\ as an example. I am actually using the full path.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: As I said, the above code is fine and there is no error. My problem is that when the data is transferred to MS Access it is put into one column. I want to be able to separate the data into different columns based on the tab delimitation of the text data.

Comment: In that case you need a schema.ini file. I am not sure what your problem is with a schema.ini?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I have got this working with a schema.ini file as @Remou has suggested.

These are the steps I went through:

1) Create an access database named "testdb.accdb" in the directory "C:\AccessDatabaseTest\"

2) Create a tab delimted file named "TestData.txt" in the directory "C:\AccessDatabaseTest\" with the following contents:

```
ID  TestColA    TestColB
1   9   TestA
2   10  TestB
3   11  TestC
```

3) Create a file named "schema.ini" in the directory "C:\AccessDatabaseTest\" with the following contents:

```
[TestData.txt]
Format=TabDelimited
```

4) Run the following F# script file:

```
#r "System.Data"

open System.Data.OleDb 

let loadData() =
    let connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\AccessDatabaseTest\testdb.accdb';Persist Security Info=False;"
    use connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    let query = "SELECT * INTO TestTable FROM [Text;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\AccessDatabaseTest].[TestData.txt]"
    use command = new OleDbCommand(query,connection)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

loadData()
```

For some reason using the command that explicitly uses the TabDelimited property

```
"SELECT * INTO TestTable FROM [Text;FMT=TabDelimited;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\AccessDatabaseTest].[TestData.txt]"
```

does not work if a schema.ini file is not used

Also you might have noticed that the connection string I used is slightly different in that it has "Persist Security Info" instead of just "Security Info" and that the F# script has use bindings on objects that expose the IDisposable interface so it gets automatically disposed of when it goes out of scope. See [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/let-use-do/) for more details.

**Edit:**

This version works without a schema.ini file . It basically converts the tab delimited file to a csv file using the open source library [F# Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html) and then loads the csv file. You can manually get it by downloading using [NuGet package manager](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/10/25/nuget-package-manager-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx) in Visual Studio.

```
#r "System.Data"
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.0.3/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"

open System.Data.OleDb 
open FSharp.Data

let loadDataNoSchemaIni() =
    let connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\AccessDatabaseTest\testdb.accdb';Persist Security Info=False;"
    // Load tsv file and save to a csv file using F# Data Csv Parser API
    CsvFile.Load(@"C:\AccessDatabaseTest\TestData.txt","\t",'"',true)
        .Save(@"C:\AccessDatabaseTest\TestData.csv",',','"')
    use connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    let query = "SELECT * INTO TestTable FROM [Text;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\AccessDatabaseTest].[TestData.csv]"
    use command = new OleDbCommand(query,connection)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

loadDataNoSchemaIni()
```

Comment: Thanks for this jeremyth, but I realize that this will only work if I have text driver which I don't. I have been trying to find a way to add a text driver to the ODBC Data Source Administration with no luck do far. I only see **SQL Server** and **SQL Server Native Client**. I will be sure to post something if I find a solution to this.

Comment: @ll_jack what sort of error do you get after running the F# script file? Are you trying first with my example?

Comment: The above example is the same as I was doing before. There is no error as the code executes just fine. The problem is that when finished, everything is put into one column in MS Access. I have been doing some research (googling) last week and I think the problem is that I don't have a Microsoft Text Driver installed. I am now trying to install Microsoft Text Driver which is proving more difficult than expected. My hunch is that the problem is to do with MS Access but currently have no evidence.

Comment: Oh so you are saying the "C:\AccessDatabaseTest\schema.ini" is not getting picked up by the OleDbConnection? Another alternative might be to convert the tab delimited file to a csv file then try load that. If you manually convert the file TestData.txt to TestData.csv replacing all tabs with commas and load that does it work?

Comment: csv works just fine for me. This problem seems to be specific to text files. Out of interest, does this work for you, ie text file with tab delimitation? In the ODBC Data Source Administration, do you see a Microsoft Text Driver in your computer?

Comment: Yeah mine loads the tab delimited file fine. I have also updated my answer with a version that works without a schema.ini file in the directory.

Comment: @ll_jack out of interest what was the school boy error in the end?

Comment: in my computer the file extension was hidden! **(http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7)** Also needed to add **CharacterSet=ANSI** to the schema.